# Ansible: shell command returns blank is fatal

Tags: shell, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to run a simple tail command with Ansible. Iterate over 3 strings until all are not found. If found loop over the tail command until all are not found.

```
   - name: Tail the logs for string
     shell: "tail -10 /path/to/log/file.log | egrep 'STRING1|STRING2|STRING3'"
     register: tail
     until: "'STRING1' and 'STRING2' and 'STRING3' not in tail.stdout_lines" 
     retries: 10
     delay: 5
```

When I run the above task and there's nothing to return, it exits with a fatal error. Even though this is the success case.

```
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "tail -10 /path/to/log/file.log | egrep 'STRING1|STRING2|STRING3'", "delta": "0:00:00.012770", "end": "2016-09-07 07:44:35.684238", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "tail -10 /path/to/log/file.log | egrep 'STRING1|STRING2|STRING3'", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-09-07 07:44:35.671468", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

I am unsure why it ends in a fatal state.

Comment: `'STRING1' and 'STRING2'` is always a true value, no matter what `tail.stdout_lines` contains.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` returns nonzero when it doesn't match anything. If you want to override its exit status:

```
shell: "tail -10 /path/to/log/file.log | egrep 'STRING1|STRING2|STRING3' ||:"
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have avoided the fatal end of the task, but it seems to always show the task as changed regardless of the output.

`until: "'STRING1' and 'STRING2' and 'STRING3' not in tail.stdout_lines"`

seems the above condition is not running.

Comment: @OmarE `'STRING1' not in tail.stdout_lines and 'STRING2' not in tail.stdout_lines and ...`. Programming is not a natural language, `and`ing strings makes very little sense.

Comment: @zerkms Even if I have one condition `until: "'STRING1' not in tail.stdout_lines"` the task still passes regardless.

Comment: @OmarE you have not provided example of the `tail.stdout_lines` and have not explained in what case the task should be treated as changed. Without those not sure how we are supposed to help you, since we cannot read your mind, sorry.

Comment: @charles-duffy Thanks for your help. Would you know why a similar command is also giving me a fatal output from Ansible.

`kill -9 \`ps -ef | grep -v awk | awk '/modules.jar|loader.jar/{print $2}'\``

If the process is already killed it ends in a fatal output in Ansible. How can we change the exit status?

Comment: @OmarE, doing process management that way such a bad idea I'm unwilling to get involved in defending/improving/fixing it. Use a real process supervision system for monitoring and restarting your services. That said, the `||:` idiom works pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

After resolving the tail command thanks the advice from @charles-duffy the issue remained with the loop condition.

Here is the correct condition:
`until: '"STRING1" not in tail.stdout and "STRING2" not in tail.stdout and "STRING3" not in tail.stdout'`

I also used `tail.stdout` instead of `tail.stdout_lines`

Thanks

Comment: BTW -- my view was, and is, that these are all side issues unrelated to your question; they're bugs, sure, but they're not the bug *you asked about*.